# string or number dictionary type parameter

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
interface NumDict<T> {
  [key : number] : T
}

export function mapNumDictValues<T,R>(dict: NumDict<T>, f: (v: T, key?: number) => R): NumDict<R> {
  let emptyDict : NumDict<R> = {};
  return Object.keys(dict).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const keyInt = parseInt(key);
    acc[keyInt] = f(dict[keyInt], keyInt);
    return acc;
  }, emptyDict);
}
```

Now I would like it to work for string indexed dictionaries as well as number indexed dictionaries, e.g. something like:

```
function mapDictValues<K extends string|number,T,R>(obj: {[id: K]: T}, f: (v: T, key?: K) => R): {[id: K]: R} {
```

However, this gets me this error:

```
error TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
```

Is there a way?

Comment: `string|number` is not a `string` and not a `number` it's a type of it's own, you'll need to cast it to either one: `{ [id: K as string]: R }`. Also, take into account that in javascript there are not number keys, if you do: `a[1] = 3` it will do `a["1"] = 3`

Comment: I checked, and you can not cast there, but as I already said, dictionary keys in js are always strings, so just do: `{ [id: string]: R }` and probably you have no need for `K`

Comment: I know that object/dictionary keys are actually strings, but on a type level Typescript allows you to enforce the usage of numbers only for keys and I am utilizing that for greater type-safety. If I use `{ [id: string]: R }` I loose that type-safety and that is exactly why I need `K`.

Comment: This: `mapNumDictValues({ "key": "value" }, (value, key) => value.length)` is fine with the compiler even though `"key"` isn't a number. So I'm not exactly sure what type-safety you mean. Are you referring to the type of the key in the passed iterator function?

Comment: Of course key is a number when the dictionary's signature is specifying it to be. TypeScript's allowance of a key of type `number` in a dictionary's type signature is not incorrect. Both `string` and `number` work fine as inputs as keys as you've already mentioned in your first comment. Of course the return type of `Object.keys` is `string[]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. As my example shows that even when you specify the indexes to be numbers you don't get type-safety: `function fn(dict: { [key: number]: string})` works well with: `fn({ 3: "hey" })` (as you wanted), but also: `fn({ "3": "hey" })` which is still ok cuz you can `parseInt` it, but what about: `fn({ "string": "hey" })`? The compiler is ok with it.  So I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: The following: `var x: {[x:number]: string} = { '3': 3 };` will result in `Index signatures are incompatible.`

Comment: Right, but not because of the index being a string but because of the value not being a string. This: `var x: { [x:number]: string } = { "3": "3" }` won't raise a compilation error.

Comment: `var x : {[x:number]: string} = {}; x['foo']='bar';` with `--noImplicitAny` will result in `element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`. Even without `--noImplicitAny` assigning `x[3]=3` will get you `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`, while `x['3']=3` will not get you any error. So, while not fool proof, there is type-safety there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface IStringToNumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
}


interface INumberToStringDictionary {
    [index: number]: string;
}

type IDictionary = IStringToNumberDictionary | INumberToStringDictionary;
```

Example:

```
let dict: IDictionary = Object.assign({ 0: 'first' }, { 'first': 0 });
let numberValue = dict["first"]; // 0
let stringValue = dict[0]; // first
```

In your case something like this:

```
interface IStringKeyDictionary<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}


interface INumberKeyDictionary<T> {
    [index: number]: T;
}

type IDictionary<T> = IStringKeyDictionary<T> | INumberKeyDictionary<T>;
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't see that back then :) This is the correct answer. Except that it has to be `IStringKeyDictionary<T> | INumberKeyDictionary<T>`, so I've edited a bit.

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is not easily accomplished (at least I can't find a way) because of how javascript treats the object keys (strings only) and typescript restrictions on index expressions (string/number/symbol/any) and the difference between the types `number | string` and `number`/`string`.

The only type-safety you managed to gain (from what I understand) is that you get an error using `noImplicitAny` (obscure error) for one case, but you are still restricted with what you can do with this dictionary.

I don't know much about your case, but it sounds like you have little to gain here in order to get decent solution, unless you really need this type-safety then I think it's better to just treat your keys as strings and get it over with, but if you do need it then I suggest that you create your own dictionary type implementations to deal with things, for example:

```
interface Dict<K extends number | string, V> {
    get(key: K): V;
    set(key: K, value: V): void;
    mapValues<R>(f: (v: V, key?: K) => R): Dict<K, R>;
}

abstract class BaseDict<K extends number | string, V> implements Dict<K, V> {
    protected items: { [key: string]: V } = Object.create(null);

    get(key: K): V {
        return this.items[key.toString()];
    }

    set(key: K, value: V): void {
        this.items[key.toString()] = value;
    }

    abstract keys(): K[];

    values(): V[] {
        return Object.keys(this.items).map(key => this.items[key]);
        // or Object.values(this.items) with ES6
    }

    mapValues<R>(fn: (v: V, key?: K) => R): Dict<K, R> {
        let dict: Dict<K, R> = Object.create(this.constructor.prototype);
        this.keys().forEach(key => dict.set(key, fn(this.get(key), key)));
        return dict;
    }
}

class NumDict<V> extends BaseDict<number, V> {
    keys(): number[] {
        return Object.keys(this.items).map(key => parseFloat(key));
    }
}

class StringDict<V> extends BaseDict<string, V> {
    keys(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.items);
    }
}
```

You'll need to create your dicts with the ctors, which is not as comfortable as using `{}`, but you do have more control over things, for example notice that when calling the map function (`fn`) in `BaseDict.mapValues` then the key will have the right type (number in case of `NumDict` and string for `StringDict`).

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, that is a decent workaround. But in actual fact I want the answer to this question, because I am using those (semi-)typed dictionaries within my own data structures. I'd rather have the inconvenience of two functions `mapNumDict` and `mapDict` than the overhead of another layer of indirection. I don't plan to call those functions outside of my own data structures anyway.